# How to show isometry of the space through plane?

Tags: isometry, vector-space-isomorphism

I am totally new to the isometries of the plane and space.
I have to prove that the map
$$R(\vec{x})=\vec{x}-2(\vec{x}\bullet\hat{n})\hat{n}$$ from $R^{3}$ to $R^{3}$ is isometry of the space $R^{3}.$
The attempt what I have made is, I took two points $\vec{x_{1}}$ and $\vec{x_{2}}$ from $R^{3}$. The image of these two after the given map 
$$R(\vec{x_{1}})=\vec{x_{1}}-2(\vec{x_{1}}\bullet\hat{n})\hat{n}$$ and
$$R(\vec{x_{2}})=\vec{x_{2}}-2(\vec{x_{2}}\bullet\hat{n})\hat{n}$$
Now I have to show that $R$ will be isometry if 
$$||R(\vec{x_{1}})-R(\vec{x_{2}})||^{2}=||\vec{x_{1}}-\vec{x_{1}}||^{2}$$
SInce $R(\vec{x_{1}})-R(\vec{x_{2}})=(\vec{x_{1}}-\vec{x_{2}})-2\big((\vec{x_{1}}-\vec{x_{2}})\bullet\hat{n}\big)\hat{n}$
Now
$$||R(\vec{x_{1}})-R(\vec{x_{2}})||^{2}=\big<(\vec{x_{1}}-\vec{x_{2}})-2\big((\vec{x_{1}}-\vec{x_{2}})\bullet\hat{n}\big)\hat{n}, (\vec{x_{1}}-\vec{x_{2}})-2\big((\vec{x_{1}}-\vec{x_{2}})\bullet\hat{n}\big)\hat{n}\big>$$
I get confused, how to proceed step by step to reach that 
$$\big<(\vec{x_{1}}-\vec{x_{2}})-2\big((\vec{x_{1}}-\vec{x_{2}})\bullet\hat{n}\big)\hat{n}, (\vec{x_{1}}-\vec{x_{2}})-2\big((\vec{x_{1}}-\vec{x_{2}})\bullet\hat{n}\big)\hat{n}\big>=||\vec{x_{1}}-\vec{x_{2}}||^{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow~ \bigg<\vec{x_{1}}-\vec{x_{2}},\vec{x_{1}}-\vec{x_{2}}\bigg>-4\big[(\vec{x_{1}}-\vec{x_{2}})\bullet\hat{n}\big]\bigg<\vec{x_{1}}-\vec{x_{2}},\hat{n}\bigg>+4\bigg(\big[(\vec{x_{1}}-\vec{x_{2}})\bullet\hat{n}\big]\bigg)^{2}\bigg<\hat{n},\hat{n}\bigg>$$
Am I right, how to show that $$4\big[(\vec{x_{1}}-\vec{x_{2}})\bullet\hat{n}\big]\bigg<\vec{x_{1}}-\vec{x_{2}},\hat{n}\bigg>=4\bigg(\big[(\vec{x_{1}}-\vec{x_{2}})\bullet\hat{n}\big]\bigg)^{2}$$

Comment: Use bilinearity of the scalar product.

Comment: @amd How can you explain sir!

Comment: Recall the basic properties of inner products.

Comment: @amd can you explain in answer sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us write $x$ instead of $\vec{x}$ and $n$ instead of $\hat{n}$. Moreover, $\bullet$ denotes the usual dot product (scalar product) on Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$. In other words, $a \bullet b = \langle a, b \rangle$ which is the alternative notation used in your question.

$R$ is a linear map because
$$R(x + y) = x + y - 2\langle x + y, n \rangle n = x + y -  2(\langle x, n \rangle + \langle y, n \rangle )n \\= x - 2\langle x, n \rangle n + y - 2\langle y, n \rangle n  = R(x) + R(y)$$
and 
$$R(\alpha x) = \alpha x - 2\langle \alpha x, n \rangle n = \alpha x - 2\alpha \langle x, n \rangle n = \alpha R(x) .$$
It therefore suffices to show  $\lVert R(x) \rVert =\lVert x \rVert$.
Simplifying your computations we get
$$\lVert R(x) \rVert^2 = \langle R(x), R(x) \rangle  = \langle x - 2\langle x, n \rangle n, x - 2\langle x, n \rangle n \rangle  \\ = \langle x, x \rangle - 2\langle x, n \rangle \langle n, x \rangle - 2\langle x, n \rangle \langle x, n \rangle + 4\langle x, n \rangle^2 \langle n, n \rangle \\ = \lVert x \rVert^2 - 4 \langle x, n \rangle ^2 + 4 \langle x, n \rangle ^2 \lVert n \rVert^2 .$$
You did not mention the assumption $\lVert n \rVert = 1$. But in that case you see that
$$\lVert R(x) \rVert^2 = \lVert x \rVert^2 .$$

Comment: Sir I have put hat on $n$ represents that $n$ is unit vector!
SIr Thank You so much

Comment: I see! But for future questions I recommend to explain precisely everything concerning notation. Otherwise you are in danger that some readers will not understand it correctly.